# How to set Disqus Share link to window.location.pathname + window.location.search?

Tags: 8, comments

Version Disqus 8.x-1.0-rc3
Drupal 8.2.5

I have a page that is built up of multiple nodes using **Twig Tweaks**.  One of the nodes has the **Disqus comment** field.  Module runs smoothly and everything, however, the **Share** url is to the node/#### instead of the page.

**Tried the following but to no avail:**

1. Updated the Disqus field's default identifier to **[current-page:url]**.
2. Overrode the node's Disque identifier manually on /node/####/edit page
3. Tried modifying `modules/disqus/js/disqus.js` (w/drush cr), so that

```js
disqus_title = document.title;
disqus_identifier = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
```

I thought #2 would work above, but it still is tied to the entity's node id.  The **Share** link always goes to /node/####.

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Just noticed that [current-page:url] does not include the search portion of the url.  The URL looks like **/something/node-title-text-here?page=5**

Comment: I don't want to do modify `disqus.js` ... I know about not overwriting contrib files.

Comment: If all else fails I'm going to research how to disable the Share button.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to add my own Javascript file and just clear the drupal settings for disqus like this:

1. Added Javascript file to `modules/custom/MYMODULE/MYMODULE.libraries.yml`

```yml
disqus-overrides:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/disqus_overrides.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
```

2. Created a new file in `modules/custom/MYMODULE/js/disqus_overrides.js`

drupalSettings['disqus']['identifier'] = '';
    drupalSettings['disqus']['title'] = '';
    drupalSettings['disqus']['url'] = '';

3. Then force this file to be loaded on every page load in `modules/custom/MYMODULE/MYMODULE.module` (this could be optimized to only load on those pages with the Disqus comment field, but I don't know how yet):

function MYMODULE_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
        $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYMODULE/disqus-overrides';
    }

Comment: I'm not vain and will not accpt my own answer.  If someone has a better solution I'll accept theirs.